# C# Regex Replace with parts of the same string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace parts of a generated code file:

```
    public System.Nullable<int> SomeInt { get; set; }

    public System.Nullable<bool> SomeBool { get; set; }

    public System.Nullable<bool> SomeOtherBool { get; set; }
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
    public int? SomeInt { get; set; }

    public bool? SomeBool { get; set; }

    public bool? SomeOtherBool { get; set; }
```

I know the code is equivalent, with the latter being just syntactic sugar. But I want to do it anyway cause it's more readable.

The regex patterns are easy enough to write,

```
System\.Nullable<.*>
```

for the whole thing, and something like

```
(?<=System\.Nullable<).*(?=>)
```

to get just the primitive type inside. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to use C#'s Regex API to implement the replacement correctly.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio search/replace?  If so, which version of VS, because they [changed the regex syntax as of VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried, `Regex.Replace()`?

Comment: No, I'm generating source files using CodeDom, and then reading the files and performing replace on them using the Regex API. This is all done from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [named capture group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx) would work:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(src, @"System\.Nullable<(?<type>.*)>", "${type}?");
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWsKlf